# Poisson confidence interval using the pivotal method

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, inference, pivot

I am trying to build a confidence interval for the Poisson distribution using the pivotal method. I have the theory down but I am struggling to come up with $h(Y, \lambda)$, the probability distribution which does not depend on the parameter.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: When you say you want "*a confidence interval for the distribution*" do you mean (as taking your words literally would imply) that you want a CI for the *distribution function*? Or do you actually mean that you want a CI for the *parameter*, $\lambda$?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, there isn't really a pivotal quantity for $\lambda$*, though it's possible to construct approximately pivotal quantities if $n\lambda$ isn't small. (I include $n$ there just in case you have multiple observations from the same Poisson. In many cases you'll just have the one count. From here on I'll just refer to $X$ and $\lambda$ as if we were using a single $X$.)

* *However*, that's not to say nothing can be done. You can derive an interval for $\lambda$ from the relationship between the Poisson and the chi-square (see the end of [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Related_distributions)). I can't say that it counts as pivotal, though.

For example, $\sqrt{X+\frac{3}{8}}$ is approximately normal with nearly constant variance (this is related to the [Anscombe transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe_transform) for the Poisson), so could be used to construct an approximate pivotal quantity (by subtracting its mean for example); $\sqrt{X}+\sqrt{X+1}$ - [Freeman-Tukey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe_transform#Alternatives) - is another, similar choice from which you could obtain an approximately pivotal quantity. (Indeed, the confidence interval [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197934/freeman-and-tukey-interval) relies on just such an approach)

To my recollection, some papers have given other quantities - if I remember where I've seen these, I'll add references.

With *large* values of $\lambda$, the simpler $\frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt \lambda}$ might be used as an approximately pivotal quantity.

But with small $\lambda$ (more generally small $n\lambda$), there's really not much that can be done - I don't think you get a function of the parameter and the data whose distribution doesn't depend on the parameter. If your $\lambda$ is down around 0.5 or 1 or 2, say, there's not much you can really do about it... the large spikes at 0, 1 and 2 change substantially in relative probability with $\lambda$ and no transformation is going to alter that.